# call value of last modified cell in specific column

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, trello, submission

Using google-script to format an email of a google form response on submission. In addition it's creating a Trello card via identical email.

In this spreadsheet, the Form Publisher writes an integer (like a counter) into a specific column for each form entry. Currently we're up to 264 or something. I want to reference the value (in this case an counter number for the form submission) in column "S" of the spreadsheet that collects the form submissions so that it is included in the subject line of the email the script is composing.

The script works except I can't figure out how to pull the new value for the cell in Column "S" into the email subject.

---

```
function init() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // Delete all triggers before making a brand new one.
  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  // Set up a new trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('submitToTrello')
       .forForm(form)
       .onFormSubmit()
       .create();

  Logger.log('Successful creation of new submitToTrello trigger.');

}


function submitToTrello(e) {

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var latestItemResponses = form.getResponses().pop().getItemResponses();


  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
    // Trello email address goes here
    var email = "matt@elevenaudiodesign.com";
    var trello = "mattshane+nb0dbsbponwfb4zegqjx@boards.trello.com";
  };

  // Subject line will be the title of the event on Trello card
  var category = latestItemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var subject = latestItemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var date = latestItemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var tech = latestItemResponses[2].getResponse();

  // Intial empty body
  var body = "";

  // Loop through recent responses and format them into string
  latestItemResponses.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    var formatted = Utilities.formatString("*** %s ***\n %s\n\n", value.getItem().getTitle(), value.getResponse());
    body = body.concat(formatted);
  });

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "[ "+category+" ] "+subject+" // "+tech+" // "+date,       body);
  MailApp.sendEmail(trello, "[ "+category+" ] "+subject+" // "+tech+" // "+date, body);  
}
```

---

Comment: I think this is a 'google-apps-script' question. Why don't you just use [`getvalue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)?

Comment: 1) You bind the event object, but don't use it. The available properties depend on whether this script is in the form or the destination spreadsheet. 2) to read the value on column S in the destination row, you will need to open the response sheet, reference the `Range` described by the `lastRow` and the S column, and read its value. Then adding that value to the subject is a simple string concatenation.